# HTML5 Session storage vs PHP Session (Cache/DB)

Tags: php, html, session, sessionstorage

I am currently updating a Web App, that I developed a couple months ago. My plan includes to integrate some HTML5 features. I'm already using the File API for the file uploads with a back fall to a POST upload.

I know that HTML5 also has the local storage / session storage API and thought about to integrate it, but I am worried, since the session has to be started in the beginning, that if the Web App is used with a browser that won't support it that the User will be without session.

So, I'm doing currently research and would like to ask you guys that question. 
Is there a way to write a back fall since serverside scripts are loaded before local scripts

I know how to check the support of session storage, and could go with a page reload / redirect but I would like to know if there is a better solution for it

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 offline storage - Alternative to Session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849280/html5-offline-storage-alternative-to-session)

Comment: I did see that post but since that is talking about ASP not PHP I made a new post, even though that Microsoft took over PHP it is not the same technology which makes the question not a dublicate Thx

Comment: Accepted answer on that link is the answer I would answer here, that's why it is duplicate to me. And what do you mean by this statement `Microsoft took over PHP` ?

Comment: whene you mean session that means Cookies ! and if the browser does not support cookies the client will not support `$_Session` and i dont think that it exists a browser that does not support cookies

Comment: galvic: As you can see, the question is about how to integrate a back fall and solutions others came up with HTML5(Javascript) and PHP. 

I can't find the English post at the moment, only in German but I read the other day that Microsoft will further develop PHP6 and integrate it into their .NET enviroment. Since this is a blog post I'm not sure how reliable it is tho. So, no panic please :)

K3rener31: That means that the storage API relies on cookies, ok thanks in that case your right it wouldn't matter.